# How to extract certain strings based on previous lines in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

Suppose I have the following string:

```
m=audio 56000 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 205 150 101
o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6
s=SIP Call
m=audio 22058 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 105 104 101
c=IN IP4 10.77.34.6
```

Now I need to search the second "m=audio" based on the searching of the string "o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6"

For this I have got the following code to search the string "o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6"

```
set buffer "m=audio 56000 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 205 150 101
o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6
s=SIP Call
m=audio 22058 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 105 104 101
c=IN IP4 10.77.34.6"
set patt "India-SIPUA"
set ipaddress "10.77.34.6"

foreach buf [split $buffer "\n"] {
  if {[regexp "o=$patt.*$ipaddress" $buf match]} {
     puts "+++++++Port==$match++++++"
     break
  } else {
     puts "\n Not found"
  }
}
```

Now what should I write in order to get the m=audio string which comes just after the string "o=India-SIPUA..."

Comment: Your existing code won't get you the result what you might already expect it to be. Since you are applying `regexp` on line by line basis, that pattern won't match at all.

Comment: I think it is not just about getting the line next to some other line. Basically, you have to match them separately. If so, apply `regexp` for them too. This is what I understood from your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dinesh the IP is at end of line starting with `o=India` the match is ok.

Comment: You want the `m=audio` line immediately after `o=India...` right? And can there be more `m=audio` in the same buffer after `o=India..`? Is this `m=audio` always on the 2nd line after `o=India`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that on one pass like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set buffer "m=audio 56000 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 205 150 101
o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6
s=SIP Call
m=audio 22058 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 105 104 101
c=IN IP4 10.77.34.6"
set patt "India-SIPUA"
set ipaddress "10.77.34.6"

if {[regexp "(o=$patt.+$ipaddress)\n(?:.*\n)*(m=audio .*)\n.*" $buffer match match1 match2]} {
     puts "+++++++Port==$match1++++++"
     puts "+++++++Audio==$match2+++++"
}
```

for the regex itself:
`(o=$patt.+$ipaddress)\n(?:.*\n)*(m=audio .*)\n.*`

- `(o=$patt.+$ipaddress)\n` First capture group `()` matching the `o=...[your pattern]` until a `\n` (not captured)
- `(?:.*\n)*` non capturing group of text with newline at end, with `*` operator match this group none or many times
- `(m=audio .*)\n` Second capture group `()` matching the `m=audio` line until `\n` (not capturing it)
- `.*` Just to match the rest of buffer, not capturing it.

For the vars in `regexp`, first is an rray of matches, the others are destination for the capture groups.

If the buffer match, print the two captured groups with prefixs.

Output:

```
 ./script.tcl
+++++++Port==o=India-SIPUA 2331 0 IN IP4 10.77.34.6++++++
+++++++Audio==m=audio 22058 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 105 104 101+++++
```

Comment: hi Tensibai, Suppose I want to split "m=audio" string as well as the number (22058) following that, then what should I write? 

I wrote: 
     regexp "(o=$patt.+$ipaddress)\n(?:.*\n)*(m=audio.$port)*\n.*" $buffer match match1 match2 match3

But it's not working...

Comment: You have to make more capture groups, like (m=audio (\d+).*). You can play with the regex on http://regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to know whether you have found the 1st pattern, in the `then` test the flag and either change the contents of `patt` to the regexp you need to match next, change the flag and continue the loop, or the 2nd pattern was found and you break the loop.